# Relation between the radius of $n$ identical circles and the radius of an enclosing tangent circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

> $n$ small circles are tangent to each other and tangent to the big circle. Here's a figure for $n=4$:
>   [image]
>
> Asking hints of how to find the reason between the radius of small circles into the big circle.

I tried doing some trigonometrics on the arcs, but failed.

Also tried this but I'm not sure about it:

Assuming $r$ is the small radius, $R$ is the radius of big one, $n$ is the amount of small circles inside the big and $x$ is the distance from the center of big circle to the center of small circle.

$$\sin\frac\pi n = \frac r x \tag{1}$$
But we don't know what $x$ is yet. We can get it from
$$x + r = R \tag{2}$$
and combine the two equations:
$$x = R - r = \frac{r}{\sin\frac\pi n} \tag{3}$$
$$R = r \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sin\frac\pi n} \right) \tag{4}$$

Therefore,

> $$R \sin\frac\pi n = r \left(\sin\frac\pi n + 1 \right) \tag{5}$$

Comment: Your formula looks correct $R=r(1+\csc(\pi/n))$

Comment: My bad, It was a n=4 attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centers of the small circles form a regular polygon with sides $2r$. You can find the circumradius of this polygon, then increase it by $r$ to find $R$.  The [circumradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius) is $\frac{2r}{\sin \frac \pi n}$  Then $R=\frac{2r}{2\sin \frac \pi n}+r$ which is equivalent to your $R\sin \frac \pi n=r(\sin \frac \pi n+1)$